# Find next occurrence from a reference table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, reference

I have searched many other questions, but cant find a usable comparison.  I have a SQL table that has a list of all the rooms at our hotel.  I want to know the next time each room is going to be occupied.  There are two tables I am looking at, one contains the name and details of each room we have, for all intents it is a static table.  The other table is a reservations table that shows check in and check out times, and has a column that references which room is being used.

Table Rooms

```
unique id   name
1           Room 3
2           Room 4
3           Suite 1
4           Suite 2
5           Suite 3
```

Table Reservations

```
unique id   start date  room id  
1            12/4/16     3
2            12/4/16     4
3            12/6/16     3
4            12/12/16    3
5            12/14/16    2
6            12/20/16    2
```

This would return only 3 values:

```
2  12/20/16
3  12/4/16
4  12/4/16
```

If also possible I would like the make it so that if a reservation is not found a null value is returned, so ultimately, the return value would be

```
Room  Next Occurrence 
1       null
2       12/20/16
3       12/4/16
4       12/4/16
5       null
```

Is there a way of doing this without my current php hack that runs 200 sql queries?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left join

```
select rooms.id, rooms.name, reservations.`start date`
from Rooms 
left join reservations on reservations.`room id` = Rooms.id
order by rooms.id
```

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find an answer, it was the simplest of solutions.  This worked brilliantly, thank you.

Comment: @user1895399  thank to you .. you can also rate my answer  as usefull if you  think this answer  is a good answer ..

Comment: you mean when   start data is > of th actual date?

Comment: yeah, it was a dumb question.  I just added an AND clause  AND ri.StartDateTime > '{AsOfDate}'